# Real Time Scheduling Policies in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, real-time

I was wondering if the two Real Time scheduling policies `SCHED_RR` and `SCHED_FIFO` can coexist in a system. 
Meaning that on one system there can be one process with `SCHED_RR` and one with `SCHED_FIFO` or all of the real time processes on a system would have the same scheduling policy.

THX

Comment: I don't see why they shouldn't be able to coexist. Neither [`man 7 sched`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html) nor [`man 2 sched_setscheduler`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setscheduler.2.html) say anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *"…wondering if the two RTS policies `SCHED_RR` and `SCHED_FIFO` can coexist in a system."*

There are [two principal options / views](http://www.real-time.org/motivation-and-intro) on solving the question ***WHEN*** they can ( safely ) coexist :
**a )**
the System-under-Review has so large pool of resources, that these can serve both of the scheduling queues of tasks so as to each and every task can still safely execute within each task's defined completion deadline
<sub>( a mathematically proven **safe surplus** of task-execution-"*capacities*" )</sub>
**b )**
a set of tasks is principally so un-demanding, that even some singularities in restricted process-executing resources still exhibit such a task-execution-capacity, that a coexistence of all the workloads, arriving from the `SCHED_RR` scheduler not only keeps to meet theirs design-side defined deadlines, but yet there still can be executed also all of the other items (still within theirs respectively design-side defined task-execution completion deadlines), coming from the **`SCHED_FIFO`**
<sub>( a mathematically proven "**under-loaded**" system, with a safely weak task-execution/completion composition, that it can safely handle all such cases, where present task-execution singular resources represent a XOR-ed flow of task executions, all still capable to meet its task-completion deadlines )</sub>

Comment: THX for that. So I guess my follow-up question is if they have different queues or are they prioritized in relation to each other. Do the `SCHED_RR` ones have limited access to the processor each time while `SCHED_FIFO` ones are executed until completion unless interrupted?

Comment: Always welcome. No, real-time systems cannot rely on a primitive fiction, like a *(relative)* "**prioritisation**" is. Real-time systems are based on mathematical proof, that all, here underscored twice, all processing is feasible to get finished within a set of pre-determined finalisation deadlines, given the resources, given the mix of tasks and given the other scheduling constraints. For linux ( non-RTS ) implementation details, feel free to re-read the source code, it is a FOSS system.